# Laravel Scheduled queue:work not working automatically need to manual trigger

Tags: laravel, queue, schedule

I have a very large cron job that need to be carry out, but server cannot handle it due to memory leaks, so i follow the suggestion to use laravel Queue, and because i can't always run `php artisan queue:work`, so i wrote a scheduled queue command that trigger every 5 minutes, but the queue not working unless i manual trigger it on server.

Here is my command for queue:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class EnsureQueueListenerIsRunning extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'queue:checkup';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Ensure that the queue listener is running.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        $this->startQueueListener();
        if ( ! $this->isQueueListenerRunning()) {
            $this->comment('Queue listener is being started.');
            $pid = $this->startQueueListener();
            $this->saveQueueListenerPID($pid);
        }
        $this->comment('Queue listener is running.');
    }

    /**
     * Check if the queue listener is running.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isQueueListenerRunning()
    {
        if ( ! $pid = $this->getLastQueueListenerPID()) {
            return false;
        }
        $process = exec("ps -p $pid -opid=,cmd=");
        //$processIsQueueListener = str_contains($process, 'queue:listen'); // 5.1
        $processIsQueueListener = ! empty($process); // 5.6 - see comments
        return $processIsQueueListener;
    }
    /**
     * Get any existing queue listener PID.
     *
     * @return bool|string
     */
    private function getLastQueueListenerPID()
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(__DIR__ . '/queue.pid')) {
            return false;
        }
        return file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/queue.pid');
    }
    /**
     * Save the queue listener PID to a file.
     *
     * @param $pid
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveQueueListenerPID($pid)
    {
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/queue.pid', $pid);
    }
    /**
     * Start the queue listener.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function startQueueListener()
    {
        //$command = 'php-cli ' . base_path() . '/artisan queue:listen --timeout=60 --sleep=5 --tries=3 > /dev/null & echo $!'; // 5.1
        $command = 'php artisan queue:work --timeout=60 --sleep=5 --tries=3 > /dev/null & echo $!'; // 5.6 - see comments
        $pid = exec($command);
        return $pid;
    }
}
```

Here is the kernel:

```
$schedule->command('queue:checkup')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

What should i do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the crone job to run automatically without initiating using command.**

**go to your terminal: and run this command**

```
crontab -e
```

**This will open server crontab file, paste this code inside, save it and exit**

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```